# How to configure the Database setting Django-MSSQL (windows)?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm new to Django and currently trying to connect my project using python 3.6.4 and Django2.1.2 with SQL server, I tried multiple drivers connectors
([libraries installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXPQA.png)),

```
> (irisha) C:\Users\MOHMMED-PC\Desktop\SOUS BUREAU\WEB\irisha\src>pip freeze
adodbapi==2.6.0.7
Django==2.1.2
django-mssql==1.8
django-pyodbc==1.1.3
django-pyodbc-azure==2.1.0.0
django-sqlserver==1.11
pyodbc==4.0.24
pypyodbc==1.3.4
python-tds==1.9.1
pytz==2018.6
six==1.11.0
```

but without result, the last driver connector I used is pyodbc:
[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiIVf.png),

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'iristest',
    'USER': 'sa',
    'PASSWORD': '1234',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1\test',
    'PORT': '1433',


},}
```

but some errors appeared:[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/815VZ.png)

> django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

thanks for helping me to find a solution.

Comment: In the previous question you asked, we already commented that you should past the *code*, *not images* of code.

Comment: I put the code.

Comment: The host contains a non-escaped backslash, what if you write `'HOST': r'127.0.0.1\test',`?

Comment: the same error appeared again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution, the problem is on  compatibility  between Django and python,  when I use pyodbc with Python 3.4.4 and Django==1.8.19 it worked, and this is what I did:

> -install Python 3.4.4 - 2015-12-21

in cmd

> pip install virtualenv test
>
> virtualenv test
>
> .\Scripts\activate
>
> pip install Django==1.8.19 pip install django-mssql
>
> pip install  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32
>
> django-admin startproject myproject .

modify setting database

```
> DATABASES = {    'default': {
>        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
>        'HOST': 'MOHAMMED-PC\SQL2014',  # Replace with host name where you have MSSQL server running
>        'NAME': 'test',  # Replace with name of the database on the MSSQL server
>        'USER': 'sa',  # Replace with user name
>        'PASSWORD': '1234',  # Replace with password    }, }
```

Answer (score 0):

"If you’re using a database besides SQLite, make sure you’ve created a database by this point. Do that with “CREATE DATABASE database_name;” within your database’s interactive prompt."

[More about database setup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/#database-setup)